# my 11 year old boy started craving white milk. Is there a health reason for that?

Tags: health

He never liked milk much I just wonder if there is a health reason for this.

Comment: What does your/his doctor say? And I'm not familiar with the phrase "white milk", do you just mean normal cows' milk?

Comment: @AE I think it's meant to be, "as opposed to chocolate milk", but I hope it gets clarified.

Answer (score 7):

11 is about when boys often start growing to their adult size; often it's a bit later, but 11 is certainly within reasonable bounds for that.

Cravings for particular foods are often a sign that you need something in them.  In the case of milk, you have a lot of things - some protein, some calcium, some vitamins, but mostly it's a rich, caloric drink.  It's not necessarily better than a lot of foods, but it's a lot more nutritious than water!  A lot of what is in milk is useful for bone and muscle development, both of which are going on at his age.  (Whey protein, from milk, is a common drink additive for body builders, for example.)

Of course, if this is excessive or makes you uncomfortable, you should always speak with your son's doctor.

Comment: "A lot of what is in milk is useful for bone … development" [citation-needed]

Comment: Umm, calcium? Or are you disagreeing with fairly conventional wisdom (in which case please post a link supporting that)?

Comment: There is no evidence supporting the claim that increasing calcium in your a diet leads to better bone growth. [here](http://archpedi.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=1769138) [are](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18065599) [links](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20949604)

Comment: Not above normal, sure, but that's the other way around from what I'm saying. Calcium _is_ needed for bone growth - even if you normally get plenty - and so it can be something you crave.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "not above normal".

Comment: Your links each concern hip fracture in elderly adults, which has little bearing on adolescent growth spurts. The first paper mentions "Calcium intake during the adolescent growth spurt is a critical factor because the demand for calcium accretion in bone is high. Most reviews of the extensive research in this area conclude that bone mass is increased with higher calcium intake during childhood and adolescence" -- little effect on bone density late in life, ok, but bones do need a source of calcium (can be dairy milk, can be other foods).

Comment: @bjb568: there's no evidence *in this answer* that calcium is useful for bone growth, but there's plenty about it in medical literature, for example http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15018485 The finding you cite: high adolescent milk intake fails to prevent hip fractures in middle-age, doesn't detract from the fact that bones have calcium in them and that this calcium comes from diet (it is of course not manufactured in the body). Whether or not this would cause an otherwise calcium-deficient 11-year-old boy to crave milk is also not established here, but then this isn't a scientific paper.